# Enumerating Typescript Types

Tags: typescript, react-native, intellisense

I'm very new to Typescript and I've seen some cool things being done in libraries such as @expo/vector-icons where in IntelliSense/Visual Studio Code the type options for string values are all available for auto-complete.

[image]

I've decided that I want to do something similar with options for colors of buttons. I've got this that I've cobbled together from a few outlets.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

type ButtonColor = {
  borderColor: string;
  fillColor: string;
};

type Dict<K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: ButtonColor;
};

const buttonDict = <K extends string>(d: Dict<K>) => d;

const ButtonColors = buttonDict({
  red: {
    borderColor: "darkred",
    fillColor: "red",
  },
  blue: {
    borderColor: "darkblue",
    fillColor: "blue",
  },
  green: {
    borderColor: "darkgreen",
    fillColor: "green",
  },
});

export type ButtonColorOption = "red" | "green" | "blue";

export default function BasicButton(props: { color: ButtonColorOption }) {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        height: "100px",
        width: "500px",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderWidth: 10,
        borderColor: ButtonColors[props.color].borderColor,
        backgroundColor: ButtonColors[props.color].fillColor,
      }}
    >
      <Text>Hello, world!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And then I can call it like this and I am able to get the auto-complete:

```js
   <BasicButton color="green" />
```

[image: Button Color Auto-Complete]

My question is this - is there an easier way to accomplish this? Or, at the very least, is there a more clean/conventional way of doing this?

I have a feeling that what I've got here is a bit convoluted.

Comment: this question has a better place here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , although i don't think the community would downvote this

Comment: Thank you, @SamridhTuladhar. I hadn't heard of that one, I'll ask there.

Comment: Here's a version with a bit less typing/duplications https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrsYB7AdgYSQGyQJygXigG8AoKKAI1wBMIcNscAuKAZ2BwEsUBzAbjJQAZp0yYGuFuy68BAXwEkAxqnaUEyFABFOS4ASgAeANJQIAD2AQU1Vmw7ceAPgAU1FgCUIKnNRMAaWA1UCRwnAEoCJyhqRRUUNXhEEKxcO0IKYO1dYBdSchwId2JBcipfOlCWACJqAEMcAGtC6mr-UuFRcVTmKGqWtsE5drLMOAgWfPJKGkqemvqmijGIQenOsSq+5fG1qGHBHkLrSY7y2np5vsXGo4hrPfIRTavqu4eR-fa5cMULMFw+lAkCCyXQPQA8mBgJxUAZGhAQEghFBgRBkaDNKFWHwgA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you! I really like that `keyof typeof` clause; that's really neat.